# JS object changed to true, still treated like false

Tags: javascript, node.js

When setting value of object to true it looks and seems it changed it but I still cant use it(as it stayed false).

```js
validateNextMove() {
    Card.setArrayNextMoveValid(this.cardRepository.findAll(), false);
    let client = this.clientRepository.findByTurn(true);
    let provjera = 0;
    if (client instanceof UNOClient) {
      let cards = client.getCards();
      for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (this.cardCanBePlaced(cards[i])) {
          provjera++;
          cards[i].setNextMoveValid(true);
          console.log(cards[i].getNextMoveValid());
          console.log(provjera);
        }
      }
      if (provjera == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
          cards[i].setNextMoveValid(true);
          console.log(cards[i].getNextMoveValid());
          console.log(provjera);
        }
      }
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: please add the array as well.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without knowing what all those methods do. NB: your braces are not balanced.

Comment: it is just bunch of values like a1,a2,a3.... letter a representing color, so when both cards are the same color, it works normally, i want to add in if the color of throwing card is different to be allowed to throwed if there is no asked color in hand(basiclly instead of picking up new one, you can throw any card when you dont have the fitting color)

Answer (score 0):

this is my method for checking if card can be place:

```
cardCanBePlaced(card){
        let current = this.discardDeck.slice(-1)[0];
        
        if(typeof current === 'undefined'){
            return true;
        }       
     
        //Check if card is allowed
        if(
            card.getColor() === current.getColor()
            ){

                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

if in above mtehod i add global variable to count if there is any available it still doesnt make it work, something like this(counter++ if there is available card of that color)

```
if(card.getColor()!= current.getColor() && counter==0){
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: You should not be adding this as an answer.  If you need to add more info to your question, then use the "Edit" link below the question and edit your question directly.  Answers are ONLY for answers.